# Find rank $A$. Find a basis of the null space and a basis of the row space of $A$; and show that they are perpendicular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\a& b\end{bmatrix}$ where $a>0$. Find rank $A$. Find a basis of the null space and a basis of the row space of $A$; and show that they are perpendicular.

My attempt at a solution:

I'm assuming that  any matrix in $A$ is of the form $x=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1 &0\\
1&0\end{bmatrix}$. From this, rank $A=1$, and a basis of the row space is $([1,0])$. However, I don't know how to find a basis of the null space in this particular problem.

Is the assumption that any matrix in $A$ is of the form $x=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1 &0\\
1&0\end{bmatrix}$ right? Since I can't find a basis for the null space, I don't know if my assumption is right. In this case, can the null space be the zero vector?

Comment: Your assumption assumes that $b=0$, which is not necessarily true. But you don't really need to assume anything like this. How could you row reduce $A$ to find the rank? Use $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

To start with, notice the columns are proportional. So that $\text{rank}(A) = 1$.

In order to find out a basis for the kernel, you have to solve the system of linear equations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix} & \Longleftrightarrow ax + by = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = -\frac{by}{a}
\end{align*}

Hence we conclude that $\ker(A) = \text{span}\left\{\left(-\dfrac{b}{a},1\right)\right\}$, whose dimension equals one.

Similarly, in order to find a basis for the row space, notice the rows are LD.

Consequently, we conclude the row space equals $\text{span}\left\{\left(1,\dfrac{b}{a}\right)\right\}$.

Based on such results, can you take it from here?